# printing folder names in bash

Tags: linux, bash

This piece of bash code, shows no folder name while there exists many folders.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in .; do
  if [  -d $file ]; then 
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

the output is only `.`
Can you explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it reads `.` as an array of size one and prints it for you. use something like this instead:

```
for file in `ls`; do
  if [  -d $file ]; then 
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use a glob instead (i.e. `for file in *; do`)